# jQuery: Calculating percentages using different div values?

Tags: jquery

I have this php webpage that grabs an ordered list that contains a rank, name and amount. I cannot change how this list gets to me. What I would like to do with jQuery however, is change the rank into an fitting percentage ((d-value-div/sum-all-values)*100).

If you run the snipped below you can see that I was able to calculate the sum of all the values. You can also see that I'm able to change the rank into the correct percentage, but only into the percentage of the first row. What I would like to see are the correct percentages in the other ranks aswell.

Current:
55.12% name1 $70
55.12% name2 $35
55.12% name3 $20
55.12% name4 $2

Goal:
55.12% name1 $70
27.56% name2 $35
15.75% name3 $20
1.57% name4 $2

How can this be done?

```js
  var sum = 0.0;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.row #d-value').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace('$', ''));
    });

    $('.row #d-rank').each(function() {
      entry = parseFloat($('.row #d-value').text().replace('$', ''));
      $(this).text((((entry / sum) * 100)).toFixed(2) + '%');
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <span class="cell" id="d-rank">1</span>
  <span class="cell" id="d-name">name1</span>
  <span class="cell" id="d-value">$70</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <span class="cell" id="d-rank">2</span>
  <span class="cell" id="d-name">name2</span>
  <span class="cell" id="d-value">$35</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <span class="cell" id="d-rank">3</span>
  <span class="cell" id="d-name">name3</span>
  <span class="cell" id="d-value">$20</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <span class="cell" id="d-rank">4</span>
  <span class="cell" id="d-name">name4</span>
  <span class="cell" id="d-value">$2</span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance,
**Tinderbox**

Comment: On my phone, so can't test, but try adding var in front of the entry variable. The way it is now, it is a global variable you want a local one.

Comment: You have four elements with the same id, id="d-value".

Comment: Also #d-value can't be used more than once. It is an id. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using IDs multiple times, which is not valid. Only the first id will ever be referenced. Change the items id to a class instead.

```
<div class="row">
  <span class="cell d-rank">2</span>
  <span class="cell d-name">name2</span>
  <span class="cell d-value">$35</span>
</div>


            var sum = 0.0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.row .d-value').each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace('$', ''));
      });

      $('.row .d-rank').each(function() {
        var entry = parseFloat($(this).sibling(".d-value').text().replace('$', ''));
        $(this).text((((entry / sum) * 100)).toFixed(2) + '%');
      });

    });
```

If you don't have the ability to change the HTML, you'll have to reference them by another method such as nth-child or looking for attr id. For example $(this).sibling("div[id=d-value]") (On mobile, will improve formatting later.)

Comment: I'll be able to change it to class. Thanks teynon for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have repeated ids in your code this may cause problem to you. I think browser count only the first one. So change id="d-value" to class="d-value"
and change this:

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell d-rank" id="d-rank">1</span>
        <span class="cell d-name" id="d-name">name1</span>
        <span class="cell d-value" id="d-value">$70</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell d-rank">2</span>
        <span class="cell d-name">name2</span>
        <span class="cell d-value">$35</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell d-rank">3</span>
        <span class="cell d-name">name3</span>
        <span class="cell d-value">$20</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell d-rank">4</span>
        <span class="cell d-name">name4</span>
        <span class="cell d-value">$2</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        var sum = 0.0;
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('.row .d-value').each(function ()
            {
                sum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace('$', ''));
            });

            $('.row .d-rank').each(function ()
            {
                entry = parseFloat($(this).next().next().text().replace('$', ''));
                $(this).text((((entry / sum) * 100)).toFixed(2) + '%');
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Edit: nvm, used .prev instead of .next. --- I have a little problem now, I did switch the amount with the rank. ($70 name1 55.12%) for some reason your fix stopped working.

Comment: Please give me the code. I can not understand what you mean.